React routing not working on deployed AWS Elastic Beanstalk instance
I successfully deployed a Spring Boot with React web application on AWS Elastic Beanstalk using a single .war archive for both frontend and backend (I put the React build under target/classes/static). However, when I try to login from the Elastic Beanstalk environment, the React routing is not able to redirect me to the main page after I put the login credentials and instead it re-renders the login page.
I tried to configure the AWS S3 bucket to support static website hosting (Static website hosting > enable, Hosting type > host a static website, Index document > index.html, Error document > index.html) by uploading the index.html from the React build on the bucket, but did not fixed the issue. If I run the .war archive locally on localhost:8080 it's working and it redirects me to the main page (/articles) after I get logged in.
pom.xml:
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>generate-resources</phase>
            <configuration>
                 <target>
                     <copy todir="${project.build.directory}/classes/static">
                         <fileset dir="${project.basedir}/client/build"/>
                     </copy>
                 </target>
            </configuration>
            <goals>
                <goal>run</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>

App.js:
<BrowserRouter>
    <Routes>
        <Route path={'/'} element={<Navigate to="/logIn"/>} />
        <Route path={'/articles'} element={<PrivateRoute><Articles/></PrivateRoute>}/>
    </Routes>
</BrowserRouter>

LogIn.tsx:
const handleLogIn = async () => {

        return logIn('logIn', user)
            .then((response) => {
                if (response.error) {
                    setError('Invalid userName or password.');

                    return;
                }

                console.log('LogIn successful: ', response);

                setCookie('jwt', response.jwt);
                navigate('/articles');
                console.log("go to /articles");
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.error('LogIn failed with error: ', error.response ? error.response.data : error.message);
                setError('Invalid userName or password.');

                return;
            })
    }

PrivateRoute.tsx:
function PrivateRoute(props: {children: React.ReactNode}) {
    const { children } = props;
    const isLoggedIn: boolean = getJWT('jwt') !== null;
    const location = useLocation()

    return isLoggedIn ? (
        <>{children}</>
    ) : (
        <Navigate
            replace={true}
            to="/logIn"
            state={{ from: `${location.pathname}${location.search}` }}
        />
    )
}

AWS S3 bucket:


I found the issue, apparently it was not related to React routing but to the way I set the cookie containing the JWT token that I'm using to make requests to the backend.
The issue was that the cookie was not saved on the browser when it got back with the login response and the private route that I'm using was redirecting me to the login page since it didn't find the cookie (as if I was not logged in). Locally it worked, but on the Elastic BeanStalk instance it didn't save the cookie since the connection was not HTTPS.
To overcome the issue and be able to save the cookie on the AWS instance, I sent it from the backend using a Set-Cookie header and also used the read-only property credentials: 'include' on each request I make (including the login one).
